# Restart Python Script using a Tactile Switch

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

is it possible to manually restart a python script using a tactile switch that will be connected to the raspberry pi? I'm currently working on a thesis project that involves using a number recognition script to determine the expiration of a license card. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would be possible using a Raspberry Pi and would likely require a thread listening for the event from the button to happen. Then call a restart function in the python script.

Edit, found this article explaining how it can work with a library called GPIO.

https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio/

Comment: If you could accept that answer that would be awesome :)